# Get username from root path using php

Tags: php, url

I am wondering if it is possible to get the to pull out just the username.

Here is an example path that I am working with:

```
/home/UserName/public_html/index.php
```

The same username is used in the IP link to the folder. Here is an example of what I am using. 
    http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~UserName/index.php

I am wondering if I can somehow use php to get this path from my server and then parse out everything but the usrername. I would then like to take that username and make it a variable that I can use else where on the page.

```
$username = UserName
```

Does this make sense?

The root issue I am having is that I am using a lot of php includes and I am having an issue with absolute/relative paths. I am thinking that by getting the username, I can make everything an absolute path instead. Maybe I am going about this all wrong.

Any advise would be awesome. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Is your code always going to run on a system with a directory structure as such?  What happens when their code is in `/var/www` or `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot` or `/var/sites/users/b/bob123/domain.com`?  See [get_current_user()](http://php.net/get_current_user) but in some PHP configurations this can return things like `nobody`, `daemon`, `apache` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Here is the code:

```
<?php
$full = dirname(__FILE__);
$folder = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
$trim = strtr($full, array('/home/'=>''));
$trim2 = strtr($trim, array('/public_html/'=>''));
$userid = strtr($trim2, array($folder=>''));
?>
```

In this example if

```
 dirname(__FILE__) = /home/USERNAME/public_html/blog/
```

Then $userid would = USERNAME

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, the best practice is to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for includes.

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/templates/footer.php');
```

Comment: This returns the wrong type of file structure. 
It returns something that looks like this:
/usr/local/apache/htdocs

I need:
/home/UserName/public_html

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good idea, since it binds everything to  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. If you then want to start moving things around, you're out of luck. If you're running PHP from CGI, the document root might not be set. Also, if the PHP script is called from the command line, there's no `$_SERVER` at all.

Comment: The `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is different per-user.  It should return `/home/user/public_html` in 99% of cases if their code is running out of that directory.

Comment: If I view the site from the domain everything looks great. But if I view it from the ip link then I get a different file structure "/usr/local/apache/htdocs/" 
How can I make sure I get the "/home/user/public_html" structure each time?

Comment: I assume you should modify your Apache configuration to serve the code, not the contrary. Look for `DocumentRoot` in your `httpd.conf` file.

Answer (score 1):

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // this gives you /folder1/folder2/THIS_ONE/file.php

$folders = preg_split('/', $path); // splits folders in array 

$what_we_need = $folders[3];
```

stolen from http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?192267-How-to-get-folder-name-out-of-a-URL